# validation page error

Tags: php, mysql

hye guys..
i have a problem where i did'nt knw what the error
i have validate page where its checks the group to identify the user
if the group is admin, the adminpage will appear..
while if the group is user, the userpage will appear..
situation:when i insert the username and password, the validate page appear with the blank page...i dont know what wrong with the code...
plz guys..help me..

here's the code:

```
<?php
session_start();            
if($_POST['id']!=null && $_POST['pass']!=null){

    $username=$_POST['id'];
    $password=$_POST['pass'];


$link=@mysql_connect('localhost','root')
    or die("Could not connect".mysql_error());
    if (!@mysql_select_db("fyp",$link)){
    echo mysql_error();
    }

$db_select = mysql_select_db('fyp',$link);
if (!$db_select) {
die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

    $sql="SELECT * from access where username='".$username."' AND password='".$password."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$result){
    die(mysql_error());
    }
    $numrecord=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($numrecord>0){
        if($group=="admin" ){
        $_SESSION['id']=$username;
        $_SESSION['pass']=$password;
        $_SESSION['group'] = $row['group'];
        mysql_close($link);
        header("Location:adminpage.php");
        }   
        elseif($group=="user"){
        $_SESSION['id']=$username;
        $_SESSION['pass']=$password;
        $_SESSION['group'] = $row['group'];
        mysql_close($link);
        header("Location:userpage.php");
        }
    }

    else{
    mysql_close($link);
    header("Location:login.php?error=2");
    }
}
else{
    header("Location:login.php?error=1");
    }

?>
```

Comment: How are the passwords stored in the database? As cleat text or as hash? You are checking now for clear text passwords. Maybe you don't get any result and the the script dies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using `mysql_fetch_array` or other function to actually fetch the rows from databse. Try this:

```
$numrecord=mysql_num_rows($result);
if($numrecord>0){

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); ////////////
    $group = $row['group'];

    if($group=="admin" ){
    $_SESSION['id']=$username;
    $_SESSION['pass']=$password;
    $_SESSION['group'] = $row['group'];
    ................
```

Also, you need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` function in your query to avoid security issues.